# Open covers in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

The definition for an open cover given in class, left me with some questions:

Since each element ($U$) of the open cover ($\mathcal U$), for a topological space ($X$), is a part of the topology ($\mathcal T$) on our space/set ($X$).

Will $X \subseteq \cup_{U \in \mathcal U}U $, as I have seen written in many places?

Should it not just be equal? The statement above would imply some element ($U$) of our open cover $(\mathcal U)$ contains things that are not in the topological space X, but since $U \in \mathcal T$ and the elements of the topology are certain open sets IN $X$, and is this not a contradiction?

Comment: If you are working with the subset topology, it can be useful to make that difference. For example if you consider the space $(0,1)$ and the standard, euclidian topology on $\mathbb{R}$, you have $(0,1) \subset \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(-n,n)$. Since in a metric space, even if it is bounded, you can still consider Balls $B_\varepsilon(x)$ bigger than your entire space. Hence it is useful not not restrict yourself to being equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your definition of cover. Sometimes we consider open covers of a subset of a topological space.

But typically when we consider a cover of topological space, then you are correct: the "$\subseteq$" is the same as "$=$" in this case.

However it is not wrong, and it does not imply that the inclusion is proper as you claim. It does not imply there are elements outside. In fact since "$\supseteq$" inclusion always holds, then "$\subseteq$" is simply equivalent to "$=$".

Misleading? Maybe. Wrong? No.